# bolt on tools -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> DOUG (DAGI) YUDOVICH is the Director of Business Information Applications for UW
>   Physicians in Seattle. The department’s primary responsibilities range from developing
>   enterprise-level Web-based reports and OLAP objects to developing database
>   applications in support of various business needs for managing data. The applications
>   vary in scope, from stop-gap applications, to **bolt on tools**, to mission critical–level
>   applications that support up to 250 users.

What does that exactly mean?

Comment: It should say "bolt-on tools".  I suggest, from context, this is similar to a software "plug-in".

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the meaning, but I would assume that this would mean add on's to some already created product or tool.

Comment: So, bolt-on, plug-in, add-on, perhaps snap-in (win)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bolt on** is an idiom in British English, but not in American English.  (Not sure about its use in other Commonwealth countries.)  [The Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/bolt-on) defines it:

> added to a main product, service, or plan as a smaller, extra part or feature, especially in business:
>
> > Davidow said the business would continue to make bolt-on acquisitions.

In this case, "The applications vary [...] to bolt on tools" refers to applications developed as after-market accessory tools for other applications.

Note I am not a native speaker of British English (I'm an American), but my impression is that the term "bolt on" does *not* imply, in British English, that the "bolt on" application runs as *part of* the thing it's "bolt on" to.  To my American ears, "bolt on" would imply something like a plug-in or module, or something that is meant to be *attached* to the referent application.  But I understand that's not what's meant in the British idiom.  For instance, if you have an application (A) which generates hard-to-parse log files, and you developed a stand-alone application (B) for parsing the log files, even though B doesn't run as part of A, in British English you could say B was a "bolt on" to A, because the whole purpose of its existence is to make using A easier or better.